# Show that $T$ is continuous and bijective if $\inf\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\} \gt 0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $\{\alpha_k\}_{k \geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\inf\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\} \gt 0.$ Consider the linear operator $T : \ell^2 \longrightarrow \ell^2$ defined by $$T(x) = (\alpha_1 x_1, \alpha_2 x_2, \cdots)$$ where $x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots ) \in \ell^2.$ Show that $T$ is continuous and bijective.

**My Attempt** $:$ It is easy to see that $T^{-1}$ exists and it is continuous and $\|T^{-1}\| \leq \frac {1} {\inf\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\}}.$ So by the virtue of open mapping theorem we can say that $T^{-1}$ is open and hence $T$ is continuous. In fact this implies that $|\alpha_k| = \|T(e_k)\| \leq \|T\|.$ So $\sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\} \leq \|T\| \lt \infty.$ Also for any $x \in \ell^2$ with $\|x\| = 1$ it is easy to show that $\|Tx\| \leq \sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\}$ and hence $\|T\| = \sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\}.$ But without using open mapping theorem can we somehow show that $T$ is continuous by showing that $\|T\|$ is bounded above by some positive real number?

Any help would be warmly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Comment: Wait, is $\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \{|\alpha_k|\} <\infty$ an assumption as well?

Comment: @popoolmica$:$ If we assume open mapping theorem this is forced if the image of $T$ is in $\ell^2$ which is given.

Comment: @geetha290krm$:$ You are misinterpreting what I said. First of all do you agree that $T^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: But if, e.g., $\alpha_k=e^k$ isn't $T$ ill-defined on sequences that decay polynomially?

Comment: @geetha290krm$:$ I am a TA of a course in functional analysis and this question appeared in a quiz. Till now open mapping theorem, closed graph theorem, uniform boundedness principle are not introduced.

Comment: @geetha290krm$:$ I agree with you. But let's assume that.

Comment: @geetha290krm$:$ So according to you there is no direct approach to this problem unless we assume some sophisticated tools. Right?

Comment: I am sorry about my earlier comments. The question can be answered without the use of Open Mapping Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\sup_n |\alpha_n|=\infty$. Then we can find $n_1<n_2<\cdots$ such that $|\alpha_{n_k}|>k$. Let $x_{n_k}=\frac  1 k$ and $x_n=0$ if $n$ is not of the form $n_k$.  Then $x \in \ell^{2}$ but $(\alpha_n x_n) \notin \ell^{2}$. Of course, $\|T\|\leq \sup_n|\alpha_n|$.

Comment: $T$ is continuous because $T^{-1}$ is continuous and hence open.

Comment: Again you are misinterpreting what I meant to say. I said that if $T^{-1}$ is a continuous surjective map then $T^{-1}$ is open. Moreover if $T$ maps $\ell^2$ into $\ell^2$ then $T^{-1}$ is the inverse of $T$ and vice versa. What does it tell us about $T^{-1}\ $? If $\inf\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\} \gt 0.$ It is easy to show that $T^{-1}$ is continuous as $\|T^{-1}\| \leq \frac {1} {\inf\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\ \{|\alpha_k|\}}.$

Comment: Nevertheless, your answer is nice. So it's not a good idea to consider a question as bad at first glance. There might be some hidden mystery in it. Thanks for your effort. Really appreciate it.